# Error for hash variable while accessing after assigning value in for loop

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash variable defined outside a for loop say

```
my %sports = (); #hash variable defined
my $count = 0; #key for the hash variable which will be used to populate the hash
```

Inside the for loop , I have populated this variable through some logic say

```
$sports{$count} = "cricket"
$count++;
```

Now when I am trying to print all the values mapped to this hash variable outside the loop , I am getting an error

I entered

```
print $count." -->  ".$sports{$count}  ;
```

I get an error as

> Use of uninitialized value within %sports in concatenation (.) or
>   string at

Comment: Seems like you actually want an array.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after the assignment: `$sports{$count} = "cricket";` It makes me sad when people don't even try to run the code they're posting... [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of,

```
$sports{$count} = "cricket"
$count++;
```

try

```
$count++;
$sports{$count} = "cricket"
```

so your `$count` will hold last used key for `%sports` hash.

Answer (score 0):

After the last assignment, you incremented the value of $count. So, the new value doesn't exist in the %sports hash. Use

```
print $count - 1, ' -->  ', $sports{ $count - 1 };
```

Also, if you're using a sequence of numbers as hash keys, you might switch to an array.

Answer (score 0):

To print all the values mapped to the hash, iterate through the keys:

```
for my $count (keys %sports) {
    print $count." -->  ".$sports{$count};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is because you are trying to access the hash value which is not assigned.

Your iterations are like this

```
$count = 0

# Lets say loop goes from 0 to 5.
# So, when $count = 5 
    $sports{$count} = "cricket"
    $count++;  # Here $count becomes 6 and loop ends

print $sports{$count}  # Outside loop, Here $count is still 6, you are
                       # trying to print $sports{6}, which is unassigned
```

You need to move the `$count++` before

```
$count++;
$sports{$count} = "cricket"
```